# Are there any groups similar to the muses in other religions?

Tags: greek, comparative

Are the muses - a set of deities, each corresponding to a specific form of art - a unique Graeco-Roman invention or are there parallels in other mythologies?

Comment: Did Greek culture invent the Muses? Did not the Muses rather invent Greek culture? Anyhow, though the standard nine names go all the way back to Hesiod, the association of each with a distinct art form is much, much later.

Answer (score 3):

Well there is the Norse "muse" [Kvasir](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.holidayyarns.com/muse.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjDm4HMkfrTAhWLhlQKHaX7DDoQFggmMAI&usg=AFQjCNEQzXG4VST02XI3MbcmNWj4RwKcIQ&sig2=p0UIo-6szEqt6zM3MJRKZw).

As far as a group of muses in another religion, no I can't think of or find any.